# SQL Performance on Select

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
select * from table (Return 10 columns)
```

or

```
select fild_a, fild_b from table
```

That makes any difference, talking about performance?

Comment: [SQLBlog](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list) You may want to have look at the this article written by @Aaron Bertrand

Comment: The second query is **much preferred** because (a) it returns only those columns needed (and thus potentially a lot less data), and (b) when you specify just the few columns you really need, there's a chance (or an opportunity) to have a **covering index** that would contain those columns and thus would speed things up even more. My personal recommendation is to **ALWAYS** explicitly specify just those (few) columns that you **really need** - don't just use `SELECT * ...` out of lazyness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference in performance Marcelo refers to is afaik true, but miniscule at best.

More to the point, using asterisks results in an unreliable result set, since any changes to the data model will be reflected in the result of the query, which may potentially break any existing code that's using that query.

Also, there's the question of indexing. If **fild_a** and **fild_b** are indexed, the latter query will be MUCH faster than the former, since the former basically automatically forces a full table scan.

Other than that, it depends on the situation: whether your selection is a part of a larger query, etc. Naturally fetching all columns and their data, and transferring it over to the application requires more resources than just getting the data you need. But for example a a part of a sub-query, the query execution planner may often realize you're not actually returning all the values. But it will still fail to use the proper indexes unless your query matches their criteria.

Comment: +1. Especially when you add that with the not smart approach of using non-validated ordinals in code 1,2,3) assuming the rows will be in a specific position - which may change when the schema changes.

Answer (score 1):

The first Query select fild_a, fild_b from table is faster than
second select * from table (Return 10 columns) Query because
There are two basic rules of querying a database table:

1. Query only the rows that you need.
2. Query only the columns that you need.

By doing "SELECT * FROM table ", you are retreiving all the rows and all the columns all the time. Is that really a necessity? If you are doing this on a "very big" table (as you as say) it is bound to take time. I suggest you should revisit the design of querying the entire table every time.
http://www.quest.com/whitepapers/10_SQL_Tips.pdf

Answer (score 1):

The second query will perform much faster because it needs less IO (doesn't have to return a whole chunks of data)

If you are returning this data to the client over a network then it would require less data packets, which again would help client get the results faster.

Comment: "Much faster" may be irrelevant. Depends on columns, amount of data, network.

Answer (score 0):

My friend told me that when using

```
select * from table
```

SQL will first of all check all columns of the table before starting the search.

When entering the desired columns the search ends up being faster. We speak of millisecond improvements.

if anyone can add more information about it, I appreciate it.

Comment: Ah, we speak of microsedonc improovement. Millisecond was too much even 10 years ago. Yes, there are advantages - mostly if you do not need columns, and transfer less data. But the lookup is irrelevant.